# google sheets - match list of rows in multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 sheets where I want to have same list of users. When I add user to [holiday] sheet, it should be also added in [trip] sheet. How to automate adding users so there is same list of user in every sheet based on first sheet? It is time consuming to copy paste list of users. Real life worksheet have 100+ sheets.

Sheet [holiday]
[image: sheet1]

Sheet [trip]
[image: sheet2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Use `={holiday!A2:B}` in ***cell_A2*** of the ***trip*** tab to automatically populate the entire list (id+name) (& other sub-tabs as well which needs to reference the holiday names list)*